# How to return return from a promise callback with fetch?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, fetch-api

I'm a bit stumped. I've forgotten how to do this.
I have a function called ext.get() that takes a parameter of url. It fetches a response from the url. The ext.get() function is meant to return the response as a json. I don't think it is doing that.

```
ext.get = (url) => {
        let myHeaders = new Headers();

        let options = {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: myHeaders,
            mode: 'cors'
        };

        //fetch get

        fetch(url, options).then(response => {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(response.json()))
            return JSON.stringify(response.json())

        });

    };
```

Comment: `return fetch(…`

Comment: Specifically [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30180679/542251)

Comment: note: `ext.get` can not return anything but a Promise - if you want it to work

Answer (score 10):

If you need the response as JSON - and considering `response.json()` effectively the same as `response.text().then(txt => JSON.parse(txt))`

```
    return fetch(url, options).then(response => response.text());
```

So, the function in full would be

```
ext.get = (url) => {
    let myHeaders = new Headers();
    let options = {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: myHeaders,
        mode: 'cors'
    };
    return fetch(url, options).then(response => response.text());
};
```

That way you aren't essentially doing `JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(json))` ... which is just `json`

However, I suspect you want a plain ol' javascript object

```
ext.get = (url) => {
    let myHeaders = new Headers();
    let options = {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: myHeaders,
        mode: 'cors'
    };
    return fetch(url, options).then(response => response.json());
};
```

You would then use this as:

```
ext.get('url').then(result => {
    // result is the parsed JSON - i.e. a plan ol' javascript object
});
```

Answer (score 5):

You are using `fetch`, which is an asynchronous API. This means that your function must also be asynchronous -- i.e. it must return a `Promise`. (You could do this with a callback, but this is 2017...)

You can't return JSON from the function because the function will return before the response from the server is available. You must return a Promise and deal with it using `then` (or [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)) in your calling code.

The simplest and best way to do this here is simply to return the result of the `fetch` call once it has been transformed. You don't want to parse the JSON but to return it as a string. This requires the [`response.text()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/text) call:

```
ext.get = (url) => {
    let myHeaders = new Headers();

    let options = {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: myHeaders,
        mode: 'cors'
    };

    //fetch get

    return fetch(url, options).then(response => response.text());
};
```

And your calling code:

```
ext.get('http://example.com').then((response) => {
    console.log(response); // or whatever
});
```

or with [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await):

```
let response = await ext.get("http://example.com");
```