# Mongoose find().exec() promise issue

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, es6-promise

Can someone explain to me why the following code returns `audiences` instead of returning an empty array?

```
return Audience.find()
  .exec((err, audiences) => {
    if (err) return errorHandler.handle('audienceService', err);

    return Promise.resolve([]);
  });
```

Comment: I could explain you just do `return Audience().find()`. You're mixing a "callback" into what you expect to return a `Promise`. The mongoose methods already return promises.

Comment: @NeilLunn: [That dupetarget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43320521/how-to-return-return-from-a-promise-callback-with-fetch) seems like quite a stretch, is there something more directly applicable to using the callback aspect of `exec` rather than the promise aspect?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Wrong link in clipboard. Was meant to be the canonical, and was also searching for the lengthy response on mongoose `exec()` which should clear up the additional confusion. Links changed.

Comment: @NeilLunn: :-) I wouldn't say [the async one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) is a dupetarget for this at all. [The other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31549857/mongoose-what-does-the-exec-function-do)'s answers address this tangentially at best, to my mind.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're returning from the `exec` **callback**. To use the promise from `exec`, use `then` on it [as shown here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html). There's also no reason for `Promise.resolve`:

```
return Audience.find()
  .exec()
  .then(audiences => [])
  .catch(err => errorHandler.handle('audienceService', err));
```

Comment: This answer doesn't address the question

Comment: Thank you for this. I've been trying to see how a full implementation of `.then()` `.catch()` with mongoose queries. Is it fine make an async function and await audiences? @t-j-crowder

Comment: @O'DaneBrissett - If you have a promise, yes, you can `await` it in an `async` function. So for instance, if it were in an `async` function, the above could be `try { await Audience.find().exec(); return []; } catch (err) { errorHandler.handle('audienceService', err); }`.

Comment: So basically once its async, you can't use `.then()`  `.catch()` you have to wrap in a try catch block? @t-j-crowder

Comment: @O'DaneBrissett - You *can*, it's just usually you don't want to, because the logical flow is usually clearer with the simple flow-control statements that `async` functions let you use instead.

Comment: So it's just not recommended I completed understand. You saved me thanks a lot @t-j-crowder