# returning a value from node-fetch

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, node-modules, node-fetch

```
exports.img = function(){
  fetch("http://aws.random.cat/meow")
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(json => console.log(json.file));
}
```

I have been trying to return the "file" value from the json i fetched but I keep either producing "promise {  }" or "undefined".
I'm able to log the info I want in the console but I haven't been able to return the value. I've been trying for hours now and need some direction. 
Also Ive already looked through these and some others.

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch#api
- [Promise pending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38884522/promise-pending)
- https://blogs.missouristate.edu/cio/2016/01/14/fetching-data-over-http-with-nodejs-using-node-fetch/
- https://medium.com/@tkssharma/writing-neat-asynchronous-node-js-code-with-promises-async-await-fa8d8b0bcd7c
- https://evie.gitbook.io/js/modules

This question is mainly to help me with node-fetch but I am in the process of working with modules as well.

Edit.

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

exports.img = async function cat(){
  var data = await fetch('http://aws.random.cat/meow');
  var json = await data.json();
  return json.file;
}
```

From the answers I was given I produced this code but still received a pending promise.

Comment: Follow this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43320521/how-to-return-return-from-a-promise-callback-with-fetch#answer-43320592